# jQuery - Edit-In-Place with CKeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, edit-in-place

Anyone know how to connect the jquery plugin edit-in-place, with CKEditor?

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeditable + CKEditor](http://blog.amps211.com/this-is-me-professing-my-love-for-jquery-and-how-i-got-ckeditor-working-with-jeditable/)

Here you have, the answer for your problem :)